# Update problem via OLE DB provider MSDASQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server

i am trying to update table via OLE DB provider MSDASQL for a linked server.

Connection is working, select statments work without problems. Update also worked until now.

Linked Server: MYSQL DB - update via MYSQL workbench works fine

But now i get the following error:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" could not UPDATE
> table "[xxx]...[yyy.zzz]". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7343)  OLE DB
> provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "xxx" returned message
> "[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.38-google-log]You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`zzz` SET
> `trn_state`=? WHERE `check`=? AND `check_pos`=? AND `checkopen_time`='
> at line 1". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

My update statement:

```
update [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]
set trn_state = 1
where trn_state = 0
```

Using sql agent :

```
USE [cgposmanager]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[create_ifc_transaction_hellotess]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

that's the stored procedure:

```
    USE [cgposmanager]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[create_ifc_transaction_hellotess]    Script Date: 12.10.2022 08:39:15 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO




ALTER procedure [dbo].[create_ifc_transaction_hellotess]

as

    update [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]
    set trn_state = 1
    where trn_state = 0
    
    insert into [dbo].[ifc_sales_transactions]
    SELECT concat(outlet,revenue_center,device_no,datename(y,checkopen_time),REPLACE([check],'-','')),
    outlet,revenue_center,device_no, device_name,[user],[check],check_pos,detail_type,
    convert(datetime,checkopen_time,104),
    getdate() timestamp1, 
    detail_number,detail_name,tax,quantity,NULL,
    total_gross,card_maingroup,card_group_1,card_group_2,
    card,null,card_counter,card_balance_current,card_balance_previous,
    case
    when detail_type = 2 then '10000'
    else article_group_no
    end article_group_no,
    case
    when detail_type = 2 then 'Kartenladungen'
    else article_group_name
    end article_group_name,
    costcentre_no,costcentre_name,account_no,
    account_name,
    company_no,company_name,department_no,department_name,external_costcenter_no,external_costcenter_name, 
    2 source_id,NULL 
    from [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]
    where trn_state = 1
    
       
    update [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]
    set trn_state = 2
    where trn_state = 1
```

Error message does not match my statement - why ?

Whats the reason ? What am I doing wrong ?

Error in provider options or linked server properties ?
Can it be a wrong setting on the other side ?

Comment: is this really the first line of the statement: `update [xxx]...[yyy.zzz]`?  Also, your error is referencing things that aren't shown in the statement provided, like check, check_pos, and checkopen_time.

Comment: that's exactly what I don't understand either !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It works. You can update a linked table or query it using 3 periods.

```
select * from LinkedServerName...TableName
```